# SyntaxError: Unexpected token import while Transpiling Reactjs app using Babel

Tags: node.js, reactjs, babeljs, server-side-rendering

I'm trying to add Server Side Rendering to my React app. I've installed the latest babel package but when I try to start the node server using

```
node server/bootstrap.js
```

I get the error "SyntaxError: Unexpected token import"

It seems babel is not transpiling my React app.
Below is the code snipet in my bootstrap.js file

```
require('ignore-styles');

require('@babel/register')({
    ignore: [/(node_modules)/],
    presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
    plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties", "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import"]
});

require('./index');
```

I'm using node 8.11.2

Below is part of my package.json file

```
"dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "^7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-react-app": "^7.0.2",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "ignore-styles": "^5.0.1",
    "react": "^16.8.3",
    "react-autosuggest": "^9.4.2",
    "react-awesome-modal": "^2.0.5",
    "react-dom": "^16.3.2",
    "react-facebook-login": "^4.1.1",
    "react-google-login": "^5.0.0",
    "react-image-lightbox": "^5.1.0",
    "react-notify-toast": "^0.5.0",
    "react-quill": "^1.3.3",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-s3": "^1.3.1",
    "react-scripts": "2.1.5"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
     "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.3.4",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0"
  }
```

Below is the entire error message

```
C:\angryusers\node_modules\react-s3\lib\ReactS3.js:1
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import Signature from "./Signature";
                                                              ^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token import
    at createScript (vm.js:80:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:139:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:616:28)
    at Module._compile (C:\angryusers\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:99:24)
    at Module._extensions..js (module.js:663:10)
    at Object.newLoader [as .js] (C:\angryusers\node_modules\pirates\lib\index.js:104:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:565:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:505:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:497:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:596:17)
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Can you share more details of your error (i.e. line, column, stack trace)?

Comment: @oneturkmen I've included as you requested. Thanks.